# PHPStorm File Watcher not working while not in focus

Tags: css, sass, focus, phpstorm, file-watcher

I have the following SASS file watcher configuration:

[image: PHPStorm SASS file watcher configuration]

My goal is to enable auto-synchronization of .SASS  & .CSS with the chrome dev-tools, [as explained here](https://medium.com/@toolmantim/getting-started-with-css-sourcemaps-and-in-browser-sass-editing-b4daab987fb0).

However, I noticed that the file watcher is active & recompile's the .SASS files only when the PHPStorm window is in focus.

Is there a way to still make it work while in the background?

Thanks!

Comment: No .. because IDE does not look for file updates/modifications then -- it only happens manually (when using "Synchronize" button) or when you enter/leave IDE window (there are more such "sync points" but they are rather internal (triggered by internal events when you are inside IDE window -- e.g. switching to internal Terminal, Executing script etc).

Comment: I guess using Gulp/Grunt watcher is what you need here.

Comment: Not sure if modern PHPStorm versions solves the issue, but a task manager is definitely the way to go here.